# ¿Solo el footer y una tabla no esta bootstrapped :/?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Me he dado cuenta varias veces de que el bootstrap no se inicia automáticamente o en todas partes en la página `index.html` que desarrollo en comparación con una página de muestra. Aqui esta el que intento reproducir :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta el que he producido :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los codigos html son los mismos y pienso que he seguido la installacion de Bootstrap correctamente. Entonces no sé poraque no finciona bien el diseño de la pagina ... ¿ tienes alugnas ideas ?

Estoy siguiendo un curso Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools: Bootstrap 4, sobre Coursera. en particular el [curso sobre componentes CSS de Bootstrap](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bootstrap-4/lecture/agf7J/exercise-video-navbar-and-breadcrumbs).

Una persona llamada MCheli lo hizo bien. Es de su código (que es idéntico al mío sobre la tabla) que viene la primera captura de pantalla  [Aqui esta su repositorio GitHub para este ejercicio](https://github.com/MCheli/Full-Stack-Web-Dev-Coursera/tree/master/Front-End%20Web%20UI%20Frameworks%20and%20Tools/Week%202%20-%20Boostrap%20CSS%20Components/conFusion). Lo mio esta [sobre Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/AntoineCompagnie/bootstrap4). El archivo se llama `index.html`.

Comment: tienes que compartir el codigo!!! el botón tiene estilo bootstrap, y el mensaje de"Warning" también, asi que probablmente si se esta cargando el estilo bootstrap. El path del shell no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con la ubicacion para el navegador.

Comment: @AlexAngelico Mi pena, acabo de agregar el nombre del archivo en el repositorio